# can Bash be configured to search string on the current input line?

Tags: bash, readline

For fast locating positions when using the command line(Yes, I'm an Emacs fan). After viewing Bash' man, I can't find such tips. Does it need to modify readline's source code to support this?

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know of a way to do it directly in the command line, but bash does support a keypress that will open the command line in your editor of choice. From the bash manpage:

```
   edit-and-execute-command (C-xC-e)
          Invoke  an  editor  on the current command line, and execute the
          result as shell commands.   Bash  attempts  to  invoke  $FCEDIT,
          $EDITOR, and emacs as the editor, in that order.
```

So hitting CTRL-x CTRL-e in emacs bindings mode (the default) or ESC v in vi bindings mode (`set -o vi` for that) will open the existing command line in the editor specified by the environment variables mentioned above. You can edit the command line, and once you save and quit the editor the command will be executed.

Comment: Problem with this is that the command will execute whether you save or `:q!`. So if you want a noop - delete everything!

Comment: @crizCraig `:q!` in vim will just quit without saving, so as far as bash knows, you just didn't make any edits. Whatever was last saved will be the command executed, and "last saved" starts out as whatever was on your command line at the moment you told bash to open it in an editor. However, there is an exception: if your editor returns a non-zero status, bash will *not* execute the command. You can do this in vim with `:cq`. One oddity with this:  whatever was on the command line before the editor was invoked will still be added to your history, even though it never executed.

Comment: This may become my favorite Bash (and ZSH) keyboard shortcut ever.

Answer (score 5):

CTRL-r (reverse-i-search) will allow you to search the current line as well as anything in your history.

If you want to jump back a couple of arguments, you can hit space, then CTRL-r again to "find again". Escape will break out of it with the cursor at the last search result.

Comment: The OP asked for a search on the _current_ input line specifically

Comment: This is a very useful answer. As someone who often types long commands and then just wants to change one thing, I use this a lot. For me, it's much less disruptive than `C-x C-e`.