# Jump to string in current line while using Bash in VI mode

Tags: bash, vi

While navigating in **BASH** using VI mode, I can jump back to a specific character (e.g. '-') of the current command line via the following command:

```
F-
```

How can I jump back to a specific string (e.g. '--path') in the current command line of **BASH**? I know navigating in VI but I did not understand how to perform regex search in current command line of **BASH**.

Comment: If it helped you, please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43005/82349), what you want doesn't seem possible. The `?word` and `/word` bindings search in *command history* rather than in the current command line.

But in vi mode, you can press `ESC v` to open the current command line in an editor. Then you can edit & save the command and it will be executed ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529726/3980816)).

Of course, as pointed out in nur-sh's answer, you can simply keep pressing B to get to the word.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the find command which searches backwards from where you are

**?word**

or you could keep pressing **B** to get to the word
(this command goes back one Word at a time).

Comment: `?` does not work in Bash command line. Am I missing something?

Comment: hope you're not typing the literal word 'word', word should be the thing you're looking for:  say you're looking for the word 'mango' . you would type            ?mango(if mango is before where the cursor is presently)  or  /mango(if mango is after where the cursor is presently)

Comment: The `/` and `?` search commands in Bash (and Korn) shell in `vi` mode look for the earlier (`/`) or later (`?`) command with the search pattern; they do no look within the current line.  I don't know of a way o search for a word in the line; I either drop into the full editor, or just use character searches (one of `FfTt;,`).